# How to manage mobs for dungeons

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a ‘dungeon’ I'll have it within it’s own worldguard region to help manage it.  I’ve tried to summon monsters with tags and then `kill @e{tag:dungeon}`.  I’ve tried creating a scoreboard objective as dungeon and then kill all mobs with the tag.

I guess either I don't fully understand or trying to accomplish something these mechanics aren't designed for.

```
/scoreboard objectives add dungeon1 dummy

/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Tag:"dungeon1"}
```

Anybody have any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Target selectors use square brackets and `=` to separate keys from values. So your kill command should be:

```
kill @e[tag=dungeon]
```

In NBT, these tags are stored in a list called `Tags`. So your summon command should be:

```
summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["dungeon"]}
```

Also, the main convenience of using tags (rather than scores) is that you don't have to create a scoreboard objective. So you can remove the `dungeon1` objective if you want.

---

As an addition, note that since `Tags` in NBT is a list of strings, you could summon the zombie with multiple tags like this, if you wanted to:

```
summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["dungeon","boss_zombie","strong"]}
```